# Playing private audio files from S3 using jPlayer with perishable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, jplayer

I have been trying to set up jPlayer on my Ruby on Rails website that uses Amazon S3 to store user's audio files.

It works perfectly for songs that are public, but because of the nature of my website the user's audio files must be private (to protect them).

So I thought that it would have no problems if it was just given a perishable link with read permissions to the file. But such is not the case.

Firebug shows me that this error is thrown:

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - *(url I provided here)*
>
> > HTTP load failed with status 403. Load of media resource *(url I provided here)* failed.

I'm very confused by this since I was able to play my private audio files with a perishable link using AudioJS before (and it still works). But I would prefer to use jPlayer if I can solve this issue.

The javascript that I used to initialize the jPlayer (straight from the demo):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "<Perishable URL goes here>"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
    });

});
```

I'm using jPlayer v2.4.0 and JQuery v1.10.1.

Any light on this issue would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!